# unable to get type of control for radcombobox in javascript

Tags: javascript, rad

I am new to radcontrols.
I want to know how to get type of control of a radcontrol using javascript.
For normal asp.net controls we write:

```
 var controlType=document.getElementById("hdnCode").type;
```

The above code will give type of control as "hidden", and for textbox it will give "text".

When i try to get type of a rad control it gives undefined as shown here:

```
 var controlType=document.getElementById("RadComboBox1").type;
```

The above code gives undefined.

Please suggest me how to get type in case of Rad Controls.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really check for the type of the control like this, these are complex objects (IScriptControls) and not simple HTML elements.

You can try the following approach to see the instances of given type (the if block shows how you can make a check only):

```
function get_allRadCombos()
        {
            var allRadCombos = [];
            var allRadControls = $telerik.radControls;
            // all RadControls are referenced

            for (var i = 0; i < allRadControls.length; i++)
            {
                var element = allRadControls[i];

                if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox && Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.isInstanceOfType(element))
                {
                    allRadCombos.push(element);
                }
            }
            // only the RadCombos are gathered into an array
            return allRadCombos;
        }
```

The $telerik.radControls is an array the RadControls create and populate, you can check a given instance by referencing it through the $find(controlClientID) method

Comment: i was struggling to get solution for so long and i compromised by doing server side code but your post helped me and nw i have done it client-site as i wanted Thank you very much it help me a lot

Comment: question: why do you have to add `Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox &&` inside the if statement? @rdmptn

Comment: If there are no RadComboBox controls on the page the type will not be registered, so accessing its member (the isInstanceOfType() method) will throw an error.
Put simply, safety :)