# Parent aspx Page not getting Reloded when Telerik RadWindow is closed

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using a RadWindow to open a pop up window from an aspx page,when i close the pop up window i want the parent aspx page to get reloaded.
i have tried many thing but didn't work in my case.
latest i tried is this

```
$(window).unload(function () {
            RefreshParentPage();
        });
        function RefreshParentPage() {
            top.location.Reload();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [recommended method](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/refresh-parent-window-on-radwindow-close.aspx)?  In the parent window -

```
<telerik:radwindow ... OnClientClose="RefreshParent" ... />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
  function RefreshParent(sender, eventArgs)
  {
     document.location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandra i have used you code and it worked for me

Comment: i had another problem with rad controls but my question was not solved,would you please recommend me something for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212730/unable-to-get-type-of-control-for-radcombobox-in-javascript